# Как изменить стандартный URL React?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

как мне изменить стандартный URL в React? На данный момент по умолчанию используется `http://localhost:3000`, мне же нужно, чтобы он был `http://localhost:3000/profile`. Я пробовал при помощи

```
<Route exact path="/">
    <Navigate to="/profile" />
</Route>
```

Это не дало результата. Единственным, что помогло, это создание файла .env и размещение в нем `PUBLIC_URL=/profile`, однако, это вызвало проблемы со всеми путями для ico,img и тп. Я пробовал для них всех
`img className='Sea' src='%PUBLIC_URL%/ico/sea (2).png' alt='Sea'/>`, но толку это не дало.
Поэтому прошу Вас подсказать, как еще можно изменить стандартный URL, или решить проблему с путями при использовании способа с .env. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Попробуйте переделать на `<Route ... element={<Navigate to="/profile" replace />} />`